# Cache issue in server for Laravel 5.4 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I am getting Cache issue and that's why url is taking wrong in network instead of siteurl/frontend/public/index.php/login.

This may be cache issue of Laravel or Ubuntu server.
Can anybody help me to resolve cache issue.

It gives 200  (from disk cache) for some files but file path is wrong.

I am attaching SS below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a cache issue. But if you think that so Clear Your Cache.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: artisan is not installed on server.

Comment: There is no any single mistake from code, I already had checked with that. It's only mistake from server configuration.

Comment: nginx or apache??

Comment: apache2 is installed on server

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may need to clear compiled view files of your Laravel application. To clear compiled view files run the following command from the terminal.

Run `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: php artisan view:clear does not work, still i am facing issue.

Comment: Click "Disable Cache" checkbox below "network tab"

press Ctr + F5 @@